# Hiding the slds-slider-label__range on the lightning-slider

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds-styling-hooks, lightning-slider

Got a number of LWC lightning-slider components. I want to hide the range label (span with class `slds-slider-label__range`). This won't work because of the shadow DOM...

```html
<div class="range-hidden">
  <lightning-slider label="Risk of breach" value={pain1} min="0" max="5"></lightning-slider>
  <lightning-slider label="Productivity" value={pain2} min="0" max="5"></lightning-slider>
</div>
```

```css
.range-hidden .slds-slider-label__range {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Looked for a styling hook but did not see one for the label range. The variant for label-hidden only hides the label and not the range label (sigh).

**Problem Solved**

Following Anton's guidance below (thanks Anton), I created a file called `/force-app/main/default/staticresources/sliders.css` with the CSS content above. Then I created a file in the same directory called `sliders.resource-meta.xml` with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="https://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <contentType>text/css</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

Then, I modified the Javascript for the component to:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import sliders from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/sliders';

export default class Discovery extends LightningElement {
  async connectedCallback() {
    await loadStyle(this, sliders); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [shadow dom in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), you can't pass CSS into child web components, such as the lightning-slider in your case.

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child.

I checked the [SLDS reference](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/slider/#Styling-Hooks-Overview) of the component, indeed I don't see any useful styling hooks.

You could try to override the styling using [static resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_create.htm) with the CSS file that contains override from your question:

```
.range-hidden .slds-slider-label__range {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Then [load](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation) it into your component. This will add your css file to the page itself, so all components can inherit the styling from it.